# How can I prevent 'Buy it now' button to redirect to the checkout page?

Tags: javascript, shopify, shopify-app

In my Shopify app I want to perform a couple of tasks before the "Buy It Now" button redirects to the checkout page in Shopify's default theme Dawn. In my theme app extension, I selected the button as a dom element and tried the preventDefault function, but it's still redirecting. How can I stop redirecting?

```
var paymentButton = document.querySelector('.shopify-payment-button');

  if (paymentButton) {
   
    paymentButton.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation();


      // things I want to do
    });
  }
```

Comment: Do you have solution? I'm looking for the solution for this

Comment: Did you get a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately no... This was a private app so I asked my client to remove that button. There must be a solution though, I know apps that can prevent redirection.